# Create a Notification Object (Email or Page) At Run Time -- Dependency Injection or Factory

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, factory

I have some code that emails me a notification when something happens.  Now I am trying to add a Page and *ALSO* remove the dependency on Email.

For reference; I have the name of the notification I want to send stored as a string in the database.  At runtime I have a list of people and a string representation of what they want to receive.

I initially thought dependency injection with ninject, but the kernel bindings got large and it seemed like I was hacking it together.

Then I thought simple factory, with Activator.CreateInstance(Email/Page) as INotifcation, but I don't know how to handle the differing constructor parameters (unless I use a common, complex property, like Employee, which has all the information I need).

So far I have something like this:

```
public interface INotification
{
    void SendMessage();
}

public class Email: INotification
{
    private readonly string _toEmailAddress;

    private string Body
    {
        get
        {
          return "Email";
        }
    }

    private static string SmtpHost
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpHost"]; 
        }
    }

    public Email( string toEmailAddress)
    {
        _toEmailAddress = toEmailAddress;
    }

    public void SendMessage()
    {
        var requestEmail = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(FromEmailAddress, FromDisplayName),
        };
        requestEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress(_toEmailAddress));

        var smtp = new SmtpClient { Host = SmtpHost };
        smtp.Send(requestEmail);
    }
}

public class Page : INotification
{
    private string ToPagerNumber;

    public Page(string toPagerNumber)
    {
        ToPagerNumber = toPagerNumber;
    }

    private static string IpAddress
    {
        get
        {
            var host = new IPHostEntry();
            return host.AddressList.Where(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString();
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage()
    {
        var pageProxy = new Pager();
        var serviceResult = pageProxy.SendPage(ToPagerNumber, "Test", true, IpAddress);
    }
```

I certainly appreciate all the feedback.  I feel like I could have accomplished this several times over, but finding that perfect solution (though I contend there may not be one) has proven onerous.

Thanks everyone!